# Integrating $\chi_\mathbb{Q}e^{\|x|}$ over counting measure.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

[image]

My solution: Since integrating over counting measure is just summation we just have to consider $\sum_{q \in Q}F(q)$ However, this sum is larger than $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}F(n)=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}e^{-1/n}=\infty$. Thus $F$ is no integrable.

b) Is true as integrable simple functions are always dense in $L^P$ spaces.

Comment: Finitely supported functions are those which vanish outside  a finite set. Simple functions are not finitely supported.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer for b) is not clear enough. Simple functions take only finitely many values but they need not be finitely supported.
If $f$ is integrable then  $\{x: f(x) \neq 0\}$ is at most countable. Suppose $f(x)=0$ whenever $x \notin \{x_1,x_2,...\}$. Define $f_n(x)=0$ if $x \notin \{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$ and $f_n(x)=f(x)$ otherwise. THen $f_n$'s are fintely supported and converge to $f$ in $L^{1}$.

Comment: What does taking on finitely many values have to do with anything? There is a standard result, e.g. Folland, Real Analysis, Proposition 6.7, that gives simple functions with support of finite measure are dense in $L^p$ for $1 \leq p < \infty$. Note that support here is just the set of values on which the function is non-zero, no closure is taken.

Comment: @KeeferRowan Your argument is correct. But OP did not clarify this point. Simple functions in general are not finitely supported, but they are in the present case. So I consider OP's answer as incomplete. Your answer also does not make this point explicit but your comment makes this clear.

Comment: Integrable simple function must have finite support.

Comment: Not in a general space. It is true for counting measure but not for general measures. So your argument is no complete. @Sorfosh

Answer (score 0):

This all looks good to me. Note that integrable simple functions are dense in $L^p$ for $p<\infty$, which of course applies here.

Comment: Simple functions take only finitely many values but they need not be finitely supported.